# Recoloring sql-injections in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

The PhpStorm IDE comes with a feature called *language injections*. This feature assists the developer while writing in a sub language while in the context of a primary language. That is, writing JavaScript in HTML or SQL in PHP.

The feature is useful no doubt, but I find the visuals distracting. Is it possible to configure the background color of a language injection in PhpStorm?

Not good; the green tint is super annoying in this case.

[image]

It is possible to disable the language injection, but that disables column-name auto-completion and other snacks that the IDE would otherwise provide:

[image]

I want a nice "quiet" background and the language completion features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can remove or change background color.

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor`
2. `Colors & Fonts | General`
3. `Code | Injected language fragment`

Based on your image (the fact that background color breaks under variables) -- your problem might be that it is overwritten by colors for actual SQL elements. If so -- check them at `Colors & Fonts | SQL`.